# VsCode tasks events do not fire

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension for VsCode. I am trying to get notifications on task events. However the events from the tasks namespace (onDidStartTask and onDidEndTask) do not fire.
This is my code:

```
tasks.onDidStartTask.apply(function(event: any) { 
    console.log(event);
});
```

I debug the extension and launch a task (build), setting a breakpoint on the console.log line.

This breakpoint doesn't get hit.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To register an event listener, you can just call the event directly, without `apply()`:

```
tasks.onDidStartTask(function(event: any) { ... });
```

With that, the `log()` call works correctly. The output is not very helpful, but that's a different issue ("Output omitted for an object that cannot be inspected").

If you wanted to use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (not that there's really any reason to), you'd have to use it like this:

```
vscode.tasks.onDidStartTask.apply(undefined, [function(event: any) { ... }]);
```

Comment: Yes, my extension is loaded. I hit a breakpoint where I hook to the onDidStartTask. I just never get to the function being called

Comment: You're right, there's actually an issue with your code. I overlooked that the first time, updated my answer with the correct fix. :)